# How to obtain an image size using Android's ImageDecoder class?

Tags: android, size, bitmapfactory, imagedecoder

Trying to get an image size using the [ImageDecoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder) I can't find any option to get only the size without decoding the image bitmap.

With [BitmapFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory) can be done with:

```
BitmapFactory.Options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
```

This setting makes the decoder to obtain only the image size without having to decode and return a bitmap. But the [ImageDecoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder) has no equivalent option.

In addition, the size seems to be known only when ImageDecoder.[OnHeaderDecodedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder.OnHeaderDecodedListener) gets called, and neither at this point there is any option to cancel the decoding and avoid returning the bitmap.